# How is koa middleware different from express middleware?

Tags: node.js, express, ecmascript-6, koa

Except for the obvious, `async/await` and the middleware signatures,  koa's middleware `app.use(async (ctx, next) => {...})` vs express `app.use(function (req, res, next) {...})`

How would koa's middleware make a difference ? Why would that be called [onion model](https://eggjs.org/en/intro/egg-and-koa.html#midlleware) ?

------ update ------

My original question probably wasn't clearly enough. I was wondering why koa middleware is better than express middleware ?

------ update 2 ------

As [Mastering Koa Middleware](https://medium.com/netscape/mastering-koa-middleware-f0af6d327a69) explained the error handling is indeed better in koa.

Comment: Called onion model by who?

Comment: By eggjs, https://eggjs.org/en/intro/egg-and-koa.html#midlleware

Comment: The page also contains the diagram that explains what they mean better than words.

Answer (score 3):

Well, in koajs, there is the option of cascading the middlewares:

An example from the koa page states this:

```
// logger

app.use(async (ctx, next) => {
  await next();
  const rt = ctx.response.get('X-Response-Time');
  console.log(`${ctx.method} ${ctx.url} - ${rt}`);
});

// x-response-time

app.use(async (ctx, next) => {
  const start = Date.now();
  await next();
  const ms = Date.now() - start;
  ctx.set('X-Response-Time', `${ms}ms`);
});

// response

app.use(async ctx => {
  ctx.body = 'Hello World';
});
```

Compared to express, the flow of the above code will be:

1. `Logger` middleware will pause execution of its own code, and move on
   to `x-response-time` middleware,
2. `x-response-time` will stat a time, then pause its code execution and
       hand control over to the next middleware (`response`),
3. The next middleware is `response`, it will set the response in the
       body, then unwind code execution back to x-response-time
4. `x-response-time` will continue its code execution from where it left
       off and calculate the time it took to set the response, then unwind
       code execution back to the `logger` middleware
5. `Logger` middleware will log the `response` time.

Given the above example, you could use this to your advantage. The first middleware (`logger`) can be swapped with one that catches exceptions, such that it will wrap all the following middlewares in a try catch block

Answer (score 2):

Express `next` is called at the end of middleware call and gives the control to next middleware. Previous middleware is unaware of how next middleware is executed. Middlewares can interact in one way, the last middleware is usually responsible for sending a request.

As [Koa 2 documentation](https://github.com/koajs/koa#middleware) explains, `next()` returns the result of next middleware in the stack, i.e. a promise:

```
app.use(async (ctx, next) => {
  const start = Date.now();
  await next();
  const ms = Date.now() - start;
  console.log(`${ctx.method} ${ctx.url} - ${ms}ms`);
});
```

Koa middlewares can interact in two ways, it's unnecessary that the last middleware in the stack sends a response, response assignment can be delegated to previous middleware. Since the response isn't sent explicitly like `res.send()` but after middleware stack execution is finished, it's possible to modify it in other middlewares (this can be used for good or bad):

```
app.use(function thirdPartyMiddlewareWeCannotChange(ctx, next) {
  if (!auth)
    ctx.redirect('/login');

  next();
});

app.use(router.routes());

router.get('/no-auth-here', (ctx) => {
  ctx.status = 200;
  ctx.body = 'hi';
});
```

Comment: I am aware of the document and the examples but I am still thinking about a "real’ example that actually takes the advantage of  that. Hence the question, BTW.

Comment: You asked about the difference, so that's the difference. I've got no good real-world example because I consider the concept of hopping between middlewares very confusing and impractical in Koa. Yet the obvious benefit of Koa middleware is that the response isn't sent before middlewares are completed, so you can change a header in another middleware and it won't throw 'headers were already sent' like Express would.

Comment: I think I better reword my question. "the concept of hopping between middlewares very confusing and impractical in Koa" , this is also my doubt as well.

Comment: The question in current state has a chance to fall into 'too broad' or 'opinion based' category because 'more suitable' is subjective. I assume a dev can be just comfortable with middleware hopping and consider it a preferred way to compose them. I updated the answer with an example for important feature of Koa middleware architecture. I had 'headers were already sent' problem I mentioned more than once in Express, it can be easily solved in Koa (often an indicator that you're doing something wrong, but not always). Koa middleware just provides more freedom, you can make use of it or not.

Comment: Thanks. As the question already got down vote I was thinking maybe it is easier I just drop it but then seeing you updating your answer several times I don't think I should do that any more.

Comment: Accidental downvotes happen, they don't necessarily mean that the question is bad. Most times they are compensated in the end. Upvoted it.

Comment: Hi I read https://medium.com/netscape/mastering-koa-middleware-f0af6d327a69 and did feel the error handling is better in koa

Comment: That's true, as long as you handle errors correctly with async..await. Koa design is quite clean because it doesn't need to maintain backward compatibility with Express/Connect.